# Adminjs given file doesnt exist

Tags: node.js, reactjs, admin-bro, adminjs

I have been trying to make my custom component for Adminjs dashboard. My project is made in Nodejs and Adminjs can be customized in React, so I created dashboard.jsx file inside components/dashboard folders, but when I implement that in Adminjs.bundle I get given file "./components/dashboard/dashboard doesn't exist". It just doesn't want to find the path to my component. please help!

i Have opened a new question with ComponentLoader:
[Adminjs ComponentLoader not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502027/adminjs-componentloader-not-found)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ApiClient} from "adminjs";

const api = new ApiClient();

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})


    useEffect(() => {
        api.getDashboard().then((response) => {
            setData(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>it works!</h1>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Dashboard
```

index.js:

```
AdminJS.registerAdapter(AdminJSSequelize)
const admin = new AdminJS({
    databases: [],
    rootPath: '/admin',
    dashboard:{
        component: AdminJS.bundle("./components/dashboard/dashboard"),
    },
    resources:[UsersResources, GuestResources, SalesResources, FinancesResources]

})
```

[image: folder structure]

Comment: can you share your file/folder structure?

Comment: Hi! i have edited my post with folder structure, please check...

Comment: this looks fine, you could try updating to 6.6.x and use ComponentLoader, maybe it'll work then https://docs.adminjs.co/ui-customization/writing-your-own-components

Comment: Hi! I have updated the package and my components, but unfortunately the same error occurs...

Comment: whats your operating system? could be a problem with how paths are parsed

Comment: Hi! it's macOS Big Sur 11....all other path imports work fine except Adminjs

Comment: Can you try `AdminJS.bundle(path.join(process.pwd(), "./components/dashboard/dashboard"))` or ComponentLoader equivalent?

Comment: Hi @dziraf I have tried ComponentLoader. Please check my other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502027/adminjs-componentloader-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this case is:

```
AdminJS.registerAdapter(AdminJSSequelize)
const admin = new AdminJS({
    databases: [],
    rootPath: '/admin',
    dashboard:{
        component: AdminJS.bundle(path.join(process.cwd(),"./components/dashboard/dashboard")),
    },
    resources:[UsersResources, GuestResources, SalesResources, FinancesResources]

})
```

However a new version of Adminjs came out and .bundle is depreciated, and you should use ComponentLoader instead which doesn't work for me. Please check my problem here: [Adminjs ComponentLoader not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502027/adminjs-componentloader-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `./components/dashboard/dashboard` with `./components/dashboard/dashboard.jsx`.

I have only experienced a bit, so I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately no, that's not the issue....