# Adminjs ComponentLoader not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, admin-bro, adminjs

I have been trying to make custom component in Adminjs 6.6.5 dashboard but Adminjs ComponentLoader not found error occurs. then i have tried to

```
import AdminJS from 'adminjs'
const {ComponentLoader} = AdminJS
```

but i get: Trying to bundle file 'file:/Users/Josip/WebstormProjects/ferry-backend/components/dashboard.jsx' but it doesn't exist

I would really appreciate help...

[image]

admin/index.js

```
import {ComponentLoader} from "adminjs";

const componentLoader = new ComponentLoader()

const Components = {
    MyDashboard: componentLoader.override('Dashboard','../components/dashboard.jsx')
}

export { componentLoader, Components }
```

index.js

```
import {componentLoader, Components} from "./admin/index.js";
AdminJS.registerAdapter(AdminJSSequelize)
const admin = new AdminJS({
    databases: [],
    rootPath: '/admin',
    resources:[UsersResources, GuestResources, SalesResources, FinancesResources],
    components:{
          edit: Components.MyDashboard
         },
    componentLoader


})
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem. You need to do the import as follows

```
import AdminJs from 'adminjs';
// And now you can use any adminjs dependencies as follows
AdminJs.ValidationError(errors)
```

My usage example:

```
if(Object.keys(errors).length) {throw new AdminJs.ValidationError(errors)} else {...}
```

Good luck with your development!